# Blazemeter Configuration for Load Distribution - Discrepancy

Tags: jmeter, configuration, location, load-testing, blazemeter

I am running a test on Blazemeter by disabling the load configuration:

[image]

In the JMeter script, I have given 181 Users (total).
The Load Distribution setting in Blazemeter looks like this: 2- Total Engines(Private- 50% each):

[image]

When I trigger the test I see this at the start:

[image]

During the test I see this:
Max user count of 362

[image]

and then to original count (181) :

[image]

**Q: Why do I see this discrepancy in total number of threads(Users)? And will I see 724 users if I change the engine count to 4? i.e. (Users given in script * Number of engines) before it returns to actual number of users?**

Answer (score 0):

If you disable BlazeMeter overrides your [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) is being executed "as it is", take a look at [documentation](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261977385233-Load-Configuration#h_01FCYANQJ8VEG0MK7EF9FAWZH3):

> If you do not want to use any overrides, instead relying on the configuration in your original script, you can disable any and all overrides.
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> 1. In the Performance tab, open a test or create a new test.
> 2. In the Configuration tab, scroll down to the Load Configuration section.
> 3. Click the toggle icon for each override you want to disable. Toggled right (and blue) is enabled. Toggled left (and gray) is disabled.
>    Once an override is disabled, the slider bar and number field is gray and will not be applied.
>    [image]
>
> To disable all overrides, ensure all toggles are set to the left (gray).

When it comes to [Distributed Test](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) execution each engine runs the .jmx script as it is so

- if you have `181` user in your Thread Group and 1 engine - you will see 181 users
- if you have 181 users and 2 engines you will see 362 users
- if you have 181 users and 3 engines you will see 543 users
- etc.

Going forward you can consider reaching out to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket), they should be able to offer much comprehensive help than anyone here.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I have got another--why does it asks for % if it is going to take the whole user count as it is in the JMeter script?

Comment: It's not about the user count, it's about [distributing the load](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261982364177-Load-Distribution) in case of testing from [multiple geographic locations](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261982364177-Load-Distribution#h_01FGQDW51BTHZYF9BPBV1A9BN4) which I think is not applicable in your case given you're using private engines.